# is it possible to send voice commands to MS team bot?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am developing a bot using MS bot framework and going to integrate with MS teams. but I have a challenge enabling voice commands for this bot via MS teams.
even though bot emulator has a little mice button, but it also cannot use for send voice commands 
[image]

is it possible to do this with MS team? I couldn't able to find any documentation regarding this.
I am using NodeJS for this project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Initial response (April 2018):
The only channels where Speech is supported are Webchat, the DirectLine channel, and Cortana

Reference: [here](http://blog.botframework.com/2017/06/26/speech-to-text/) on Microsoft's Bot Framework Team blog

> The Bot Framework now supports speech as a method of interacting with
>   the bot across Webchat, the DirectLine channel, and Cortana

Updated (Feb 2019) :
See Bill answer below, there is also now a preview for voice and video for Teams channel

Comment: Is there any object where we can receive this speech?

Answer (score 5):

The voice input is not yet support in Microsoft Teams.

Comment: could you please give me a reference?

Answer (score 4):

Support for voice and video bots is now in technical preview. Please see these links for more information:

- [Calls and online meetings bots in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/calls-and-meetings/calls-meetings-bots-overview)
- [Microsoft Graph APIs for calls and online meetings](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/calls-api-overview)